# Optgroup and option HTML snippet by json array

Tags: jquery, json

i getting a json array like

```
   [{"Childid":17,"ChildName":"A","Parentid":81,"ParentName":"AA"},  
   {"Childid":2,"ChildName":"B","Parentid":81,"ParentName":"AA"},
   {"Childid":6,"ChildName":"B","Parentid":82,"ParentName":"AB"},
   {"Childid":5,"ChildName":"A","Parentid":82,"ParentName":"AB"}]
```

from this i trying to build a select list . but got stuck in optgroup situation.
first i trying to find all unique parent name from the array. this will serve as opt group.

```
 var cnames = [];
                   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    if ($.inArray(value.ParentName, cnames) == -1) {
                        cnames.push(value.ParentName);
                    }
                });
```

then doing iteration in both of the arrays and populate the options [Child name and Property].

```
 $.each(cnames, function (index, value) {
   var begin = index;
   data = $.map(data, function (item, a) {
   if (value == item.ParentName) {
   return begin == index ? "<optgroup label='" + item.ParentName + "'><option value=" + item.Childid + ">" + item.ChildName + "</option>" : "<option value=" + item.Childid + ">" + item.ChildName + "</option>";
  }
});
});
```

but i getting the output like .

[image]

cause begin is always =0 after loop.can i avoid these iteration just everything in one single call.

**Update:**

---

Made the change like

```
 $.each(cnames, function (index, value) {
                    var begin = index;
                    data = $.map(data, function (item, a) {
                        if (value == item.ParentName) {
                            begin += 1;
                            return begin-1 == index ? "<optgroup label='" + item.ParentName + "'><option value=" + item.Childid + ">" + item.ChildName + "</option>" : "<option value=" + item.Childid + ">" + item.ChildName + "</option>";
                        }

                    });
                });
```

*but this wont close the optgroup .*

Answer (score 0):

**THIS SOLUTION COULD HELP YOU** 
You can optimize this code and here is a rough attempt to the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Optgroup and option HTML snippet by json array</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var data = [
                        {"Childid":17,"ChildName":"A","Parentid":81,"ParentName":"AA"},  
                        {"Childid":2,"ChildName":"B","Parentid":81,"ParentName":"AA"},
                        {"Childid":6,"ChildName":"B","Parentid":82,"ParentName":"AB"},
                        {"Childid":5,"ChildName":"A","Parentid":82,"ParentName":"AB"}
                       ];

            /*
            We will convert the avobe array something like below:
            {
                'AA' : [
                            {"Childid":17,"ChildName":"A","Parentid":81,"ParentName":"AA"},
                            {"Childid":2,"ChildName":"B","Parentid":81,"ParentName":"AA"}
                        ]
                ,

                'AB' : [
                            {"Childid":6,"ChildName":"B","Parentid":82,"ParentName":"AB"},
                            {"Childid":5,"ChildName":"A","Parentid":82,"ParentName":"AB"}
                        ]

            }
             */
            var groupedData = {};
            $.each(data, function(i,d){

                if(typeof groupedData[d.ParentName] === 'undefined'){
                    groupedData[d.ParentName] = [];
                }

                groupedData[d.ParentName].push(d);

            });


            /*
            Now we will create the final DOM 
             */
            groupedData = $.map(groupedData, function(gd, i){
                var $group = $('<optgroup></optgroup>')
                            .attr('label',i);

                $.each(gd, function(_gdi, _gd){
                    $group.append(
                        $('<option></option>')
                        .html(_gd.ChildName)
                        .attr('value',_gd.Childid)
                    );
                });

                return $group;  

            });

            (function($, undefined){

                $(function(){

                    /*
                    Rendering the output on document ready
                     */
                    $("#grouped").empty();
                    $.each(groupedData, function(i,$optGroup){
                        $("#grouped").append($optGroup);
                    });

                });

            })(jQuery);

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <select id="grouped">
        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's too late, but if you haven't figured out the solution yet, I hope It helps you.

Comment: Congratulations.Your solution may help others so I suggest you to answer it yourself.